# C# ListView Image/Icon margin/padding

Tags: c#-4.0, listview, icons, margin, padding

Is it possible to reproduce what is on the picture below in ListView, padding/margin icon to the right.

http://img801.imageshack.us/img801/4043/listview.png

My first question here, so I couldnt post the picture here.

Basically I need to move the ListView icon more right, I am reproducing file/directory browser, so the fails that are in a directory need to be below them and slighty right like in the picture, I have everything else figured out.

Comment: Is this a web application or a desktop application, are you using windows forms or asp.net web forms? There is a ListView type in web forms and a ListView in windows forms and they are significantly different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using a `TreeView` control:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dtsdfkx.aspx

But if you insist on hacking a `ListView` to render this way, you'll simply have to take over drawing each row yourself. You can do so using the `OwnerDraw` property, though be warned that there's a lot of corner cases here so you should do a lot of reading to see what people have had to deal with when implementing this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.ownerdraw.aspx

Comment: Thank for the answer, I can't use TreeView because I won't support multiselect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't konw exactly your problem, but using item.**IndentCount** works for me.

To work you need:

```
 listCode.Width = 300; // set width
 listCode.View = View.Details; // using mode view Details
 listCode.Columns.Add("Code", 150); // add a columns
```

[Microsoft IndentCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.indentcount?view=netframework-4.7)

[image]